# Java: How do you find the highest file number and increment it?

Tags: java, file, increment

So, I've written a code to create a file, but first it uses an if statement to check if a file exists and if it does it should increase an integer by 1, though I have a feeling I need to run the check after the increment, but for now I should at least get file1 and file2.

```
public void createNewCSV() throws IOException {

    int stepped = 1;
    //TODO: Find the highest number in the series of files
    File file = new File("_GAMES/" + getSaveName() + "_" + stepped + ".csv");

    //TODO: If the filename matches create a file-[higest number + 1].csv
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File exists");
        Path filePath = Paths.get("_GAMES/" + getSaveName() + "_" + (stepped++) + ".csv");
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());
        try {
            final BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File don't exists");
        Path filePath = Paths.get("_GAMES/" + getSaveName() + "_" + stepped + ".csv");
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());
        try {
            final BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The prints tell me if the file does or doesn't exist properly. I have a feeling that using int stepped = 1; is where it's falling apart. Does anyone know how I can get the stepped++ to work?

Comment: You want `++stepped`.

Comment: That was brilliantly simple. Why is it in most cases the ++ comes at the end but here it precedes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pre increment 'stepped'. Change this

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("_GAMES/" + getSaveName() + "_" + (stepped++) + ".csv");
```

to this

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("_GAMES/" + getSaveName() + "_" + (++stepped) + ".csv");
```